# Should I use crossprod or base functions in R to calculate squared norm of distace of two vectors?

Tags: r, performance, machine-learning, linear-algebra

I've seen in many places (for instance, [in the `rbfdot` function here](https://rdrr.io/cran/kernlab/src/R/kernels.R) and [here](https://rdrr.io/cran/rdetools/src/R/rbfkernel.R) ) people calculate the squared norm of the distance of two vectors using the following formula

[image: norm]

In the `R` programming language this becomes

```
crossprod(x) - 2*crossprod(x, y) + crossprod(y)
```

In the links above, and  in many other places people use exactly the `r` formula above to compute the squared norm of the distance of two vectors. However, I've tried to benchmark it against simply squaring the entries and summing up, i.e.

```
sum( (x-y)^2 )
```

And it seems to me that the base R version is faster:

```
# Create reproducible vectors
set.seed(123)
n <- 10^7
x <- rnorm(n)
y <- rnorm(n)
```

```
system.time(crossprod(x) - 2*crossprod(x, y) + crossprod(y))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.054   0.000   0.054
```

```
system.time(sum( (x-y)^2 ))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.027   0.024   0.051
```

What am I missing?

I am wondering which option is faster cause I'm tring to write code to obtain a Kernel matrix using an RBF function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`crossprod()` is a wonderful function that lives a fairly hidden existence and should be used much more. To compare the computation time you should use a package that enables you to do that more precisely.

We can compare the computing time using the `microbenchmark` package:

```
set.seed(123)
n <- 10^8
x <- rnorm(n)
y <- rnorm(n)
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(crossprod(x) - 2*crossprod(x, y) + crossprod(y), 
                               crossprod(x-y), 
                               sum((x-y)^2))


Unit: milliseconds
                                              expr      min       lq      mean   median        uq      max neval cld
 crossprod(x) - 2 * crossprod(x, y) + crossprod(y) 470.7079 491.7889  537.0879 502.9029  525.2929 1392.929   100  a 
                                  crossprod(x - y) 533.9799 575.4948  870.1463 588.7248  615.8091 4524.261   100   b
                                    sum((x - y)^2) 542.8631 589.2234 1087.4885 610.5433 1220.1261 5423.189   100   b
```